# refactoring the OrderBy expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I would like to be able to refactor out the **OrderBy** clause in a linq expression.

Here is an example of a refactor of the **where** clause

before:

```
results = ctx.ActiveUsers
    .Where(u => u.CompanyID != 1 &&
           (u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchString)
           || u.Email.ToLower().Contains(searchString)
           || u.Company.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString)))
    .OrderBy(u =>  u.LastName ).ThenBy(u => u.FirstName)
    .Select(u => new Employee {
      ID = u.ID
      , FirstName = u.FirstName
      , LastName = u.LastName
      , Email = u.Email
      , CompanyName = u.Company.Name
      , CompanyID = u.CompanyID.ToString() });
```

---

after:

```
results = ctx.ActiveUsers
    .Where(Employee.GetExpression(searchString))
    .OrderBy(u =>  u.LastName ).ThenBy(u => u.FirstName)
    .Select(u => new Employee {
      ID = u.ID
      , FirstName = u.FirstName
      , LastName = u.LastName
      , Email = u.Email
      , CompanyName = u.Company.Name
      , CompanyID = u.CompanyID.ToString() });
```

---

```
private static Expression<Func<User, bool>> GetExpression(string searchString)
{ 
    Expression<Func<User, bool>> p = (u => u.CompanyID != 1 &&
                       (u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchString)
                       || u.Email.ToLower().Contains(searchString)
                       || u.Company.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString)));
    return p;
}
```

I was wondering if the same type of thing would be possible except I would like to refactor the **Orderby** expression.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You'll need to give an example of what kind of refactoring you want. I can see what you did for a searchString, but an ordering isn't really like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to actually take a string such as "LastName", "FirstName" etc, I'd do something like:

```
var unordered = ctx.ActiveUsers
                   .Where(Employee.GetExpression(searchString))
                   .OrderBy(ordering)
                   .Select(u => new Employee {
                       ID = u.ID,
                       FirstName = u.FirstName,
                       LastName = u.LastName,
                       Email = u.Email,
                       CompanyName = u.Company.Name,
                       CompanyID = u.CompanyID.ToString() });
```

and add a new OrderBy extension method:

```
public static class UserQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<User> OrderBy(this IQueryable<User> source,
                                                  string ordering)
    {
        switch (ordering)
        {
            case "LastName":
                return source.OrderBy(x => x.LastName);
            case "FirstName":
                return source.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);
            case "Email":
                return source.OrderBy(x => x.Email);
            case "Company":
                return source.OrderBy(x => x.Company);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown ordering");
        }
    }
}
```

You certainly *could* do this using reflection, but unless you have a significant set of properties (or you want to use the same routine for different entity types) a switch statement is easier.

Answer (score 1):

thanks jon,

that answer put me on the right path for now... However, 
I need to preserve the **ThenBy** clause in my order. so while the solution below is not dynamic it still preserves the **ThenBy**

```
var unordered = ctx.ActiveUsers
                   .Where(Employee.GetExpression(searchString))
                   .MyOrder()
                   .Select(u => new Employee {
                       ID = u.ID,
                       FirstName = u.FirstName,
                       LastName = u.LastName,
                       Email = u.Email,
                       CompanyName = u.Company.Name,
                       CompanyID = u.CompanyID.ToString() });
```

---

```
public static class UserQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<User> MyOrder(this IQueryable<User> source )
    { 
        return source.OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenBy(x => x.Email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with Jon on using lambdas where possible to avoid typos etc. However, if you genuinely can't do this (for whatever reason), I've looked at fully-dynamic `OrderBy` in the past. See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/9ca28e3f0205bb87/7d931ec0e2356d21#7d931ec0e2356d21) for an example tested on LINQ-to-SQL (but it should be OK with EF in theory).